# PowerShell command runs immediately instead of waiting for batch input

Tags: powershell, batch-file

When I use this simple batch code it runs the PowerShell command immediately, it should be waiting for the input of number '1' before executing the command.

The code:

```
@echo off
:start
Echo 1. Choose to run CMD as admin
set number=
if '%number%'=='1' goto a
:a
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs
goto end
:end
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set /P number=
if "%number%"=="1" goto a
```

The `/p` instructs "wait and assign input"

Double-quotes required to delimit strings

Comment: @Lieuwe To add on, I'd suggest using `"Start-Process cmd -Verb runAs -NoNewWindow"`

Comment: Despite the necessary change as answered by @Magoo, the `powershell` command will still run regardless of the value of `%number%`. This can be fixed easily by moving `goto end` to a new line above `:a`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something along these lines:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo 1. Choose to run CMD as admin
Set/P "number="
If "%number%"=="1" GoTo a
GoTo end

:a
PowerShell -C "& {Start-Process Cmd -Verb RunAs -A "/K", "CD/D", "\"%~dp0""}"

:end
Pause
```